# How to remove roblox from ubuntu

Tags: wine, winetricks

So I installed this game that just found out about called Roblox to Ubuntu using [this link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ve9xRgOKb_Y&t=342s), but it was pretty boring, so I want to uninstall it. Will you please help me?

Steps in video:

1. `sudo apt install git`
2. `git clone https://github.com/roblox-linux-wrapper/roblox-linux-wrapper.git`
3. `wget https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/563966858462625822/853901578376708106/wine-tkg-staging-fsync-git-6.10.r3.ge3cca687.7z`
4. extrach .7z file installed in home directory

5.`sudo apt install wine`

6. `roblox-linux-wrapper/rlw`
7. click "Browse for web binaries"
8. select the other folder installed in home directory then go to bin then hit ok
9. hit "Yes"

Then it installs

List of things that didn't work:

- `wine uninstaller` -Not listed
- `sudo apt purge roblox` -E: Unable to locate package roblox

Comment: if you need more information just ask

Answer (score 0):

i just manually deleted all files related to roblox by finding with the "files" software then deleting them.

Comment: Bad idea and could totally mess up the OS. You use the reverse command you used to install it for example apt get app is now apt remove app